# Passing data from StructA to VCA, and then from VCA to VCB

Tags: json, swift, delegates

i hope im not breaking any rules, I've got a problem when im trying to pass data from struct to A and from A to B, now the problem happens when im trying to pass the data from B to C. it all works fine when i use delegates from A to B.
before i post my code, i would mention few things:

- I parse JSON and use delegate to pass the data from A(is my struct) to B
- I would like to send data from VCAA to VCB.
  Here's my code:

my struct:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

// MARK: - Struct Protocol
protocol QuizBrainDelegate {
    func didUpdateQuestionsArray(questionsArr: [Questions])
    func didUpdateMessage(message: String)
}

// MARK: -
struct QuizBrain {
   
    let urlString = "https://5fa952f1c9b4e90016e6a5be.mockapi.io/data"
    
    
    var delegate: QuizBrainDelegate?
    
    // MARK:  API Request.
     func performRequest() {
        if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
            let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, respone, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print("There's an error \(error!)")
                }
                if let safeData = data {
                    self.parseJSON(with: safeData)
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        }
    }
    
    
    /// parsing JSON method to parse the JSON
    /// - Parameter data: The data returned by the server
     func parseJSON(with data: Data)   {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        do {
            let decodedData = try decoder.decode(Root.self, from: data)
            
            
            let questionsArr = decodedData.data.questions // an array of questions
            let thankUMessage = decodedData.data.thank_you_message
            
            
            //passing the quiz arr to our Quiz's VC:
            self.delegate?.didUpdateQuestionsArray(questionsArr: questionsArr)
            self.delegate?.didUpdateMessage(message: thankUMessage)
            
            
        } catch {
            print("There was a problem with parsing JSON \(error)")
        }
        
    }
    
    // MARK: - Struct Methods:
    
    /// This func gets the next question everytime we answer the question
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - questionNum: a counter of the current question number.
    ///   - numOfQuestions: a counter of total amount of questions.
    /// - Returns: returns the new value of questionNum which is the counter of our question number.
    func nextQuestion(questionNum: Int, numOfQuestions: Int) -> Int {
            return questionNum + 1
    
    }
    
    
    /// Func sets the score of the player
    /// - Parameter scoreNum: the total score number.
    /// - Returns: returns the score with 5 points once the user answers right
    func getNumOfCurretQuestion(scoreNum: Int) ->Int {
        return scoreNum+1
    }
}
```

my VCA:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

protocol QuizVCDelegate {
func changeTitle(_ message: String?)
func updateUserOptions(_ optionsArr: [String])
}

class QuizViewController: UIViewController, QuizBrainDelegate {
    

    @IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var answerOption1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var answerOption2: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var answerOption3: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var answerOption4: UIButton!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var currQuestionLabel: UILabel!
    
    

    var currentQuestionCounter = 0   // user's current number.
    var numOfQuestion = 0 // counter of total questions.
    var numOfOptions = 0 // counter of total options for each question
    var quizBrain = QuizBrain() // an instance of struct QuizBrain for following MVC.

    var messageToDisplay = ""
    
    var quizArr = [Questions]() // array of Q and A
    var storedAnswers = [String]() // an array of stored answers of the user
    
    
     var delegate: QuizVCDelegate?

    
    
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        
        quizBrain.performRequest() // Calling the URLRequest.

    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        quizBrain.delegate = self
    }

    

    
    @IBAction func answerButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        guard let userAnswer = sender.currentTitle else { return }
        
        storedAnswers.append(userAnswer) // Storing the User's answers.
        
        delegate?.updateUserOptions(storedAnswers)
        delegate?.changeTitle(self.messageToDisplay)
       
        
        
        sender.pulsate() // lets the user knows that he answered the question.

        numOfQuestion = quizBrain.nextQuestion(questionNum: numOfQuestion, numOfQuestions: quizArr.count)
        if numOfQuestion == quizArr.count { // checking if its equal to the total of questions in the array.
            switchScreen()

        }
        
        //to make smooth transitaions im using a timer to update the UI:
        if numOfQuestion < quizArr.count {
        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.5, target: self, selector: #selector(updateUI), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
        }
    }
    
    
    
    // a func that updates all the UI
    @objc func updateUI() {
        
        questionLabel.fadeTransition(0.4) // fade animation to our questionLabel
        self.questionLabel.text = quizArr[numOfQuestion].question
        
        while numOfOptions < quizArr[numOfQuestion].options.count {
            
            switch numOfOptions { // 2-4 Options.
            case 0: // none
                self.answerOption1.setTitle(self.quizArr[numOfQuestion].options[numOfOptions].value, for: .normal) // Updates option1
            case 1: // Joe
                self.answerOption2.setTitle(self.quizArr[numOfQuestion].options[numOfOptions].value, for: .normal) // Updates option2

            case 2: // Trump
                self.answerOption3.setTitle(self.quizArr[numOfQuestion].options[numOfOptions].value, for: .normal) // Updates option3

            case 3:
                print("There's a case 4")

            default:
                print("There's a problem with Options Switch Statement")
            }
            numOfOptions+=1
        }
        
        numOfOptions = 0
        
        currQuestionLabel.fadeTransition(0.4) // fade animation to our currentQuestion
        currQuestionLabel.text = "Total: \(currentQuestionCounter)/\(numOfQuestion)" // updates the score.
        
    }
    
    
    
    /// func to update the arr with the JSON decoded questions and answers.
    /// - Parameter questionsArr: an array of question objects.
    func didUpdateQuestionsArray(questionsArr: [Questions]) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.quizArr = questionsArr
            self.updateUI()
        }
    }
    
    
    func didUpdateMessage(message: String) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.messageToDisplay = message
            print(self.messageToDisplay)
        }
       

    }
    
    
    
    // a func which presents our Thank you VC.
    func switchScreen() {
        let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
        if let viewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "sbThanks") as? UIViewController {
            viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
            viewController.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve

            self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    
}
```

my VCB:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit


class ThanksViewController: UIViewController, QuizVCDelegate {
   
    func updateUserOptions(_ optionsArr: [String]) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.choosenAnswers = optionsArr
        }
    }
    
    
    func changeTitle(_ message: String?) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.titleLabel.text = message
        }
    }
    
    
    
    
    
       
    var titleLabel = UILabel()
    let bodyLabel = UILabel()
    var choosenAnswers = [String]()
    var quizVC = QuizViewController()
    
    
    
    fileprivate func setupLabels() {
        titleLabel.lineBreakMode = .byClipping // avoiding the 3 dots.
        titleLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Futura", size: 20)
        titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
        titleLabel.textAlignment = .center

        
        bodyLabel.text = "Your Answers:\n\(choosenAnswers)"
        
        bodyLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        bodyLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
        bodyLabel.textAlignment = .center
    }
    
    
    fileprivate func setupStackView() {
        let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [titleLabel, bodyLabel])
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.spacing = 8
        view.addSubview(stackView)
        
        
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, constant: -100).isActive = true
    }
    


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        quizVC.delegate = self
        
        setupLabels()
        
        
        setupStackView()

        view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTapAnimations)))
        
        
        
    }
    
    
    
    @objc fileprivate func handleTapAnimations() {
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: .curveEaseOut) {
            
            
            self.titleLabel.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -30, y: 0)
            
        } completion: { (_) in
            
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
                self.titleLabel.alpha = 0
                self.titleLabel.transform = self.titleLabel.transform.translatedBy(x: 0, y: -100)
                
            })
        }
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.5, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: .curveEaseOut) {
            
            
            self.bodyLabel.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -30, y: 0)
            
        } completion: { (_) in
            
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
                self.bodyLabel.alpha = 0
                self.bodyLabel.transform = self.bodyLabel.transform.translatedBy(x: 0, y: -100)

                
            })
        }
        

    
}
    
}
```

Comment: Where do you assign this `var delegate: QuizVCDelegate?` property? Try to debug/print and see what is `nil`. The problem probably is that you don't assign delegate or it gets deallocated, you something similar.

Comment: @vpoltave its weird but its nill :| now i get it, it just passes the func cause its nil, the problem is why its nil if i set it at VCB to be self.

Comment: I'm glad that you hear me and post it here :)

Comment: @vpoltave ye but the problem is idk why its nil if i set it up at the VC, i set the delegate as self :| its really weird.